# Factory reset Huawei mate 20lite doesn´t work

Tags: screen, restore, hard-reset

I have a Huawei mate 20 lite, ago a time a switch the screen for a generic screen, actually the new generic screen works fine I never get an error with the touch, the problem is that ago a time I forgot my pin code and I remember that I can use it by Factory reset and then put my google account and use my phone, then when I enter to factory reset the phone request to me touch yes and then my screen don´t works
I try use a OTG and Keyboard, but it fails, any suggestion was very helpul at this moment.

Comment: use the volume buttons not touchscreen

Comment: I prove that , but doesn't works

Comment: https://www.hardreset.info/devices/huawei/huawei-mate-20-lite/recovery-mode

Comment: Right, I believe that I need do a downgrade , but I don't know about what software I should use for it.

Comment: Because my phone have Android 9 and the recovery interface was upgrade

Comment: or maybe re-connect your volume flex cable